# Initialize struct with a union inside

Tags: c, struct, unions

I'm trying to initialize a struct which has a union inside and am not sure how to do it correctly. The code is part of a bigger GitHub Repository, so I don't want to change the initial code. Here's the Struct :

```
typedef struct SYP_encoder_stru {
char name[15];      
u8 type;            
s16 val_min;        
s16 val_max;        
s16 value;          
u8 step;            
u8 miditype;        

union {
    u8 midicc;          
    u16 midirpn;        
    u16 midinrpn;       
};
u8 mapping;         
u16 wordstart;      
u16 ebpos;          
} SYP_encoder_struct;
```

If I want to create an Encoder Struct in another file, would this be right?:

```
SYP_encoder_struct enc1 = {
"OSC1 Shape", //name
0,            //type
0,            //val min
127,          //val max
0,            //value
1,            //stepping
0,            //miditype
20,           //midicc?? what about midirpn and midinrpn
0,            //mapping
0,            //wordstart      
0             //ebpos
};
```

I'm just not sure because of the Union. Is this how to initiliaze a struct if it has an union inside? What if I want to initiliaze midirpn or midinrpn instead of midicc?

P.S.: The Code is written in C, sorry forgot to mention.

Comment: what langauge is it? C and C++ are two different languages, please only tag the one that applies

Comment: And AFAIK, the rules for C and C++ are different w.r,t initialization — C has designated initializers which solve most of the problems, but C++ does not.  Even in C, you can only initialize one of the members of a union, but you can choose which one.  Specify `.midirpn = 37` or whatever.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, it is written in C

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to initialize a struct like this depends on the newest version of C that your compiler can handle.

The example you gave is perfectly valid, and is called a designated initializer.

If your compiler can handle C99 or newer, then you can use compound literals like this:

```
SYP_encoder_struct enc1 = (SYP_encoder_struct){
.name = "OSC1 Shape", .type = 0, .val_min = 0, .val_max = 127, .value = 0,
.stepping = 1, .miditype = 0, .midicc = 20, .mapping = 0, .wordstart = 0,
.ebpos = 0 };
```

Alternatively, you can individually assign to each element in the struct:

```
SYP_encoder_struct enc1;
strcpy(enc1.name,"OSC1 Shape",strlen("OSC1 Shape"));
enc1.type = 0;
enc1.val_min = 0;
enc1.val_max = 127;
enc1.value = 0;
enc1.stepping = 1;
enc1.miditype = 0;
enc1.midicc = 20;
enc1.mapping = 0;
enc1.wordstart = 0;      
enc1.ebpos = 0;
```

As to the `union` aspect of the struct, the members `.midicc`, `.midirpn`, and `.midinrpn` are members of an anonymous union, which means they can each be accessed directly i.e. `enc1.midicc`, `enc1.midirpn`, `enc1.midinrpn`, **but** since they are members of a union inside the struct, they reside in overlapping memory, so it doesn't make sense to initialize more than one of them at a time.

If you want to initialize `.midirpn` or `.midinrpn` instead of `.midicc` you can, but those three union members live on-top-of-each-other, so to speak, so only one can be used at a time.

Comment: You don't need to use a [compound literal](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5); you could drop the cast notation and the `{ … }` part is a valid [designated initializer](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9).

Comment: Compound literals were added in C11, not C99 (and they are not needed here). Designated initializers were added in C99.

Comment: @Ian Abbot that is incorrect. See ISO/IEC 9899:1999 6.5.2.5

Comment: C99 has [§6.5.2.5 Compound literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.2.5).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are correct, but I think the compound literal is cleaner. I can add a note

Comment: @WillisHershey Yes, sorry. A brainfart on my part. Designated initializers and compound literals were both from C99.

Comment: Cleanliness is next to godliness, and beauty is in the eye of the beholder, and other similar trite hogwash.  I'd prefer not to use the compound literal notation — what follows the `=` must be an initializer for the type.  But I also learned C 15 years before compound literals were part of the language, which probably colours my views (rosy-tinted pink, or thereabouts).  Designated initializers and compound literals were major beneficial features in C99 — I just wish they'd created a way to repeat initializers for the elements of an array, so C could match the functionality of Fortran 66 (IV)!

Comment: Unfortunately the functionality of Fortran 66 is not something I can claim to know anything about, but I do know that C implemented the `restrict` keyword to gain some Fortran-like power, so I'm sure C will have repeated-initializers eventually

Answer (score 1):

The union in the struct should given a variable name, such as "union_v":

```
typedef struct SYP_encoder_stru {
  char name[15];
  u8 type;
  s16 val_min;
  s16 val_max;
  s16 value;
  u8 step;
  u8 miditype;

  union {
    u8 midicc;
    u16 midirpn;
    u16 midinrpn;
  } union_v;
  
  u8 mapping;
  u16 wordstart;
  u16 ebpos;
} SYP_encoder_struct;
```

And you should set the member using the [designated initializer](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9) format "`.member = value`" one by one, and set the union variable directly such as "`.union_v.midicc = 20`" for `midicc`, or "`.union_v.midirpn`" for `midirpn`.

```
SYP_encoder_struct enc1 = {
      .name = "OSC1 Shape",  // name
      .type = 0,             // type
      .val_min = 0,          // val min
      .val_max = 127,        // val max
      .value = 0,            // value
      .step = 1,             // stepping
      .miditype = 0,         // miditype
      .union_v.midicc = 20,  // midicc?? what about midirpn and midinrpn
      .mapping = 0,          // mapping
      .wordstart = 0,        // wordstart
      .ebpos = 0             // ebpos
  };
```

Comment: Anonymous unions are perfectly fine from C11 and later

Comment: Note that the question correctly uses an anonymous union which means that the OP can drop the `.union_v` part altogether.

Comment: But  C language don't support anonymous union

Comment: Which C language are you referring to?  C11 and C18 both do.  Granted, C90 and C99 do not, but they're far from being the current standard.  C2x (almost certainly going to be C23) is almost ready — it will support them too, of course.